# PHP Session Synchronisation

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, synchronization

I am developing a WebApp in PHP. The user will be able to click a button and the PHP code will end up calling a system exec. Since the WebApp will be using AJAX, there is the possibility that the user could click the button twice, or indeed click another button which would start another exec process.

Now, I know that I could write a little javascript that would disable the buttons until the single event has been completed. However, this is client side enforcement, which can easily been overwritten.

Is there somethig I could do on the PHP side to stop things like this happening? In my head, I have an idea of having a session variable act as a "semaphore" and before every script is executed, this variable would be checked and must return 0 before the script could continue.

Am I going about that the right way? Or does that just open a can of worms for deadlocks/race conditions?

Thanks

Update:
Just to put it into context, the system I'm developing will be used to start, stop, and reimage Virtual Private Servers. If the reimaging button was pressed, the PHP script will call some bash script to start to re-image the VPSes. However if a user tried to start the VPS while this was being done....

Comment: Why do you need this? What's wrong with posting something twice? Especially when user definitely wants it.

Comment: The user isn't posting anything. The user would be starting a backend system process that would cause havoc if ran twice at the same time

Comment: To be clear, do you care only about one user spawning multiple processes here? Or do you need to ensure that no two users have a process running simultaneously?

Comment: The former. I need to ensure that a single user can't start calling my PHP script manually multiple times to involk processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `jQuery.ajax()` and set the option `async` to false:

> **async** Default: true By default, all requests are sent asynchronously
>   (i.e. this is set to true by default).
>   If you need synchronous requests, set
>   this option to false. Cross-domain
>   requests and dataType: "jsonp"
>   requests do not support synchronous
>   operation. Note that synchronous
>   requests may temporarily lock the
>   browser, disabling any actions while
>   the request is active

You could use it like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "file.php",
    async: false,
    data: data,
    success: function(return){
        alert("Success: "+return);
    }
});
```

If you want to add a loader just apply it as:

```
startLoader();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "file.php",
    async: false,
    data: data,
    success: function(return){
        alert("Success: "+return);
    }
});
endLoader();
```

However you PHP idea is simply not a good one. Opening a session and do all the process for this kind of thing is just useless and slow your script down. You should be asking yourself: Do I really need to block this?

If the answer is yes then do this:
Create a table called `processes` in you database. Inside that table create 2 fields:
One will be the process identifier: `process_id`; the second will be the process status: `process_status`. The first is an integer you will define with sha1(IMAGE).
The second will be an integer: `1` for "busy", `0` for "free".

Then you could do something like this:

```
SELECT process_status FROM vps_processes WHERE process_id = sha1(CURRENT_IMAGE);
```

And check whatever it is `1` or `0`. If it is `1` then block the script; If it is `0` then you query:

```
UPDATE vps_processes SET process_status = 1 WHERE process_id = sha1(CURRENT_IMAGE);
```

then run what you have to run and at the end of the script query:

```
UPDATE vps_processes SET process_status = 0 WHERE process_id = sha1(CURRENT_IMAGE);
```

Comment: But i don't want the browser to be locked. I want my nice loading animated GIF swirling around and the user to be able to do some other things. I literally need some server-side enforcement as if I'm disabling a select few buttons.

Comment: @jtnire, The browser will not be blocked, It will just ignore the AJAX calls that will follow the first. Server side enforcement are really expensive. Think about it.

Comment: Incidently, I'm using sessions for my login system as well, so the session will already exsist

Comment: @jtnire, the only solution that crossed my mind is about using the database. Do you already have a database use in your script?

Comment: Yup, I do indeed. The database is heavily used. Are you suggesting that I move my "semaphore" into the database rather than store it in the session?

Comment: @jtnire, sessions are unpredictable. The could expires and block all other process for nothing. I updated my answer (look at the bottom).

Comment: Thanks for your excellent answer. However, I want to limit this on a per user basis, not globally. So how would I modify the above code? Could I just create a new field in my VPS table called 'busy' and if set to true, just don't run any other processes?

Comment: @jtnire, I don't get it. It is not globally. Use these query where you need them. I didn't got: "I want to limit this on a per user basis"...

Comment: Using your processtype and processstatus table, I would have to define lots of processtypes for each VPS, or create one table per VPS (bad idea). Is my idea of using a single field "busy" in my VPS table ok? I want to limit the process on a per VPS basis (i.e. the same process is allowed to be run at the same time, as long as it's for a different VPS). Thanks

Comment: If you have different VPSs then just replace the `process_type` field to `process_id` field instead and call the table `vps_processes`. Gonna update my code.

Comment: but my question is, why have a seperate table at all? Why can't I just have a boolean (called "busy") in my current VPS table? I am of course assuming that all processes will be locked on this single boolean

Comment: @jtnire, Oh yes. If you have already a VPSs table then just use it. Why not? I didn't know that.

Comment: Thanks. It would be appreciated if you could update your answer to show that i could use a single Bool in my VPS table, and toggle that between true and false. Just so the next person finds it useful :) It's your answer, so you don't have to if you don't want to.

Comment: @jtnire, I highly discourage you from using booleans in table. Just use 1 as true and 0 as false. And my current answer use 1 and 0 as well. If you select that field and put it into a if ($from_db) {} clause it'll automatically consider it true if 1 and false if 0.

Comment: I would probably use an int and call it state, so I can get some info back. E.g. 0 would be ready, 1 general busy, 2 reimaging in progress, 3 disabled etc..

Comment: @jtnire, Yep if you need of them it's better to do as you said.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you want it to be a server-side solution makes me suspect that you don't trust the user here. Then you obviously can't use the session structure since that's also possible to circumvent by the client. Instead, you'll have to lock the single IP address or some similar approach. Maybe have a folder with lock files, where you create a file named after the IP performing the request.

Comment: How can the session structure be overridden?

Comment: By not sending session cookies, or by simply starting another simultaneous session (other session id in the cookie)

Comment: But I'm sure there are way to prevent multiple sessions being started by the same user..

Comment: If you ensure there's only one session per user you can use a session variable for locking.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to enforce the per-user limit between different machines, you could always use http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php to lock the operation on a file called `lock.$username`

Alternatively, you could simply not care about enforcing the limit, since there are only limited number of php processes that are going to run at the same time anyways.